# R - newdata has X rows but variables have X rows

Tags: r, linear-regression, machine-learning-model

I have a dataset dimensions 1142obs in 454 variables.
I've used 'caret' to separate into training and testing datasets.
training =858 obs of 99 var
testing =284obs of 99 var

I make a linear regression model like so (apologies in advance for the extra $ sign before response, which I include here otherwise it won't show correctly):

```
lm1 <-lm(training$$response ~ training$balloons, data=training)
```

I then try to make a prediction like so:

`lm.predict <-predict(lm1, newdata=testing)`

R comes up with:

```
Warning message:  
'newdata' had 284 rows but variables found have 858 rows
```

`lm.predict` also generates a vector 858 numbers long, instead of 284.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Cut down your problem to a minimal reproducible example and supply data or generate it. For your problem I can reproduce with a data frame with two columns (we don't care if its 99 or 2 columns):

```
training = data.frame(response=runif(858), balloons=runif(858))
testing = data.frame(response=runif(284), balloons=runif(284))
```

Now you are fitting the model thus, and getting this error:

```
lm1 <-lm(training$response ~ training$balloons, data=training)
lm.predict <-predict(lm1, newdata=testing)
## Warning message:
## 'newdata' had 284 rows but variables found have 858 rows
```

Your problem is because you are specifying *vectors* in the model (ie columns of `training` using the `$` column notation) and also specifying a data frame in the `data` argument (which is ignored). You get the same error if you leave it out:

```
> lm1 <-lm(training$response ~ training$balloons)
> lm.predict <-predict(lm1, newdata=testing)
Warning message:
'newdata' had 284 rows but variables found have 858 rows
```

If your observations are coming from a data frame then you don't need to specify the data as vectors, you give a formula which is evaluated in the context of the data frame:

```
> lm1 <-lm(response ~ balloons, data=training)
```

and then:

```
> lm.predict <-predict(lm1, newdata=testing)
```

which is 284 predictions as expected.